# How to make infra-doc link to crate without adding crate to dependencies

Tags: rust, rustdoc

Rust allows to make links in documentation in the form

```
/// link to structure [Foo](foo::Foo) in crate foo
```

To make this work the linked crate should be in dependencies section in Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
foo = "1.0"
```

What to do if I want to make such link, but do not want to make my crate dependent on `foo`? For tests and examples this is achieved by dev-dependencies option in Cargo.toml:

```
[dev-dependencies]
foo = "1.0"
```

But this doesn't work for building documentation with `cargo doc`.

Comment: Does it work with `cargo doc --examples`?

Comment: You can always link to https://docs.rs.

Comment: No,  cargo doc --examples doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, manually create link to docs.rs will work. And infra-doc links to elements of standard library creates links to docs.rs. It's sad that I can't create such kind of link for arbitrary crate and have to add it to dependencies instead